# What do you call a table of booleans?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently working on a table that will most likely only contains booleans column ( like `isAdmin`, `isThisRole`, `hasThisPrivilege` etc. ) that will be linked to a user kind of table, and I was wondering if there were a specific name to this kind of table pattern?

Comment: A taboo? ... But really, I usually call those tables `control` tables.  Not sure if there is a "proper" name.

Comment: From your example columns, you might consider calling it a user_role table.

Comment: Thanks guys but i'm not talking about the way to name it, but the way it's named. I thought it had a specific name like a reference table or a truth table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never heard of a specific name for that type of table.

The closest thing I can think of is *properties*, but properties typically includes other scalars, not just booleans.

I would call it a properties table, in which all the properties happen to be booleans.

Comment: `UserProperties`

Comment: I didn't want to assume the properties were for users.

Comment: i edited my post afterward, adding the precision. Thanks nonetheless Bill.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like how to refer to this table is less important than the fact that this type of table is going to cause you issues down the road: Every time you need to add a new user attribute, you're going to have to create a new column, which can quickly lead to nightmares with performance (your table is going to take up a lot of space), queries (which column did you need to check again?) and maintenance.

You might want to consider using an entity-attribute-value approach (e.g. having a table of `RolesAndPriveleges`, and having an intermediate table (`UserRoles`) with a foreign key to both the user and role/privelege. That way, you don't have to do a DDL statement to add a new role/privelege.

For more information, see https://sqlblog.org/2009/11/19/what-is-so-bad-about-eav-anyway.